# Get c#-specific name for a given framework System.Type?

Tags: c#, types

I have a Type (via reflection, for example).

I have the value of the Name property on, for example, String... that's "System.String".  I want to see "string" ("int" instead of "System.Int32", etc, etc).

Can anything in the framework (or the language) give me that?  Can I convert a Framework type name to a language type name (or, alternatively, get the language type name to begin with)?

Comment: What is more interesting is how you'll solve the problem for rendering generic types. The type that C# thinks of as "C<int>.D<string>" is rendered to string by the CLR as "C`1+D`1[System.Int32,System.String]".

Comment: `Nullable<T>` might also be a boundary-case worth shortening to `T?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get language specific type aliases by using CodeDom classes

```
var cs = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var vb = new VBCodeProvider();

var type = typeof (int);
Console.WriteLine("Type Name: {0}", type.Name); // Int32
Console.WriteLine("C# Type Name: {0}", cs.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type))); // int
Console.WriteLine("VB Type Name: {0}", vb.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type))); // Integer
```